# Two different versions of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

The FTC corollary given in wikipedia is

if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then

$$\int_a^bf(x)dx = F(b) - F(a).$$

My book gives a different version.

If $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[a, b]$, then

$$\int_a^b f'(x)dx = f(b)-f(a).$$

Are these two versions equivalent? If so, how can I see that they are?

Comment: Are you sure about “continuous and differentiable”? You probably meant “continuously differentiable” here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, fixed the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that FTC states is,
$$\int_a^b \textrm{some function}=\left[\textrm{it's antiderivative}\right]_a^b$$
holds whenever $\textrm{some function}$ is continuous on the closed interval.

It's your choice to call the function $f$, with its antiderivative being $F$, in which case it'd require $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$. Or you may call the function $f'$ with its antiderivative being simply $f$, in which case it'd require $f'$ to be continuous over $[a,b]$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are equivalent.

Suppose that the first version holds. If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then $f$ is an antiderivative of $f'$ and therefore$$\int_a^bf'(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(b)-f(a).$$Now suppose that the second version holds. Let $F$ be an antiderivative of $f$. Then$$F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^bF'(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bfx)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: In your first equation, it should be $\int_a^bf'(x)\,\mathrm dx=f(b)-f(a)$.

Comment: @Angel Sure! I've edited my answer. Thank you.